# Is there a linear transformation in $R^2$ that does this?

Tags: linear-transformations

Is there a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that preserves the $x$ coordinates of points and that maps all the lines with slope $m\in \mathbb{R}$ to the horizontal line $y=0$?

Comment: projection onto the $x$-axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $(x,y)\mapsto (x,0)$ pereserves $x$ coordinates and maps *any* line (except vertical ones) to the horizontal line $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want horizontal lines you can use
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
-am&a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ ($a=0$ gives the solution suggested by Hagen).